# Login name on website in asp.net c# on label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have searched on different sites how to get login name on label in asp.net using c# but i can't find the exact answer.There is login control .i don't want to use that .I just want to display a login name on a label when user log in.Can any one help me please in this issue.
i will be really thankful to you

Answer (score 4):

The username will be stored in `User.Identity.Name`. Assuming you have a Label with an ID of Lbl1 on your page...

```
Lbl1.Text=User.Identity.Name;
```